# Microsoft Reciprocal License: include source even for unmodified binary?

Tags: licensing

The [Microsoft Reciprocal License](http://wixtoolset.org/about/license/) (here taken from the WIX toolset I use) has the following sentence:

> For any file you distribute that contains code from the software (in source code or binary format), you must provide recipients the source code to that file along with a copy of this license

Does that mean I have to provide the source code even if I only use the unmodified (original) DLL in binary format? Note that this unmodified DLL contains code from the software, although it was not compiled by me.

What does *provide* mean? Shall I provide 11 MB of source code as part of my application (install the source on hard disk) or can I provide it as an extra download as well?

Answer (score 1):

> Does that mean I have to provide the source code even if I only use the unmodified (original) DLL in binary format?

Not if you just link to the DLL from your software.  Read the license again:

> For any file you distribute **that contains code from the software** (in source code or binary format), you must provide recipients the source code to that file along with a copy of this license

(the software being the DLL, or its original source)

**Provide** means to supply the source code to the person to whom you're distributing the software (the "user").

Comment: I am distributing `Wix.dll` (installing together with my software) and `Wix.dll` contains code from the software.

Comment: Given I provide the Wix source as separate download next to my software (two download links), would that be sufficient?

Answer (score 1):

The .Net Foundation has clarified that installers built using Wix do not count as derivative works: http://wixtoolset.org/about/license/

> Sometimes the reciprocal license is incorrectly interpreted to also
>   apply to bundles, packages, and custom actions built using the WiX
>   toolset. The Outercurve Foundation has previously provided this
>   statement below to clarify which now the .NET Foundation reaffirms:
>
> > The WiX toolset (WiX) is licensed under the Microsoft Reciprocal
> >     License (MS-RL). The MS-RL governs the distribution of the software
> >     licensed under it, as well as derivative works, and incorporates the
> >     definition of a derivative work provided in U.S. copyright law.
> >     OuterCurve Foundation (and the .NET Foundation) does not view the
> >     installer packages generated by WiX as falling within the definition
> >     of a derivative work, merely because they are produced using WiX.
> >     Thus, the installer packages generated by WiX will normally fall
> >     outside the scope of the MS-RL, and any of your source code, binaries,
> >     libraries, routines or other software components that are incorporated
> >     in installer packages generated by WiX can be governed by other
> >     licensing terms.